# jquery control chaining this loses scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was wondering if someone new how to keep a control with chaining in scope of the "this" key word. It breaks out of the chain when using .find(this).click does anyone know how to keep the chain from breaking

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mycontrol = function() {
        $(window).resize(function() {
            alert('resize')
        }).scroll(function() {
            alert('scroll')    
        }).find(document).bind('init', function() {
            alert('scroll')
        }).ready(function() {
            $(this).trigger('init');
        }).find(this).click(function() {
            alert('click'); // $(this) loses scope here 
        });
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycontrol').mycontrol()
});
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code, you haven't closed the `mycontrol function`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, you should be able to just save the value of `this` before you start your chaining:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mycontrol = function() {
        var that = this;
        $(window).resize(function() {
            alert('resize')
        }).scroll(function() {
            alert('scroll')    
        }).find(document).bind('init', function() {
            alert('scroll')
        }).ready(function() {
            $(that).trigger('init');
        }).find(that).click(function() {
            alert('click'); // $(this) loses scope here 
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i thought of that and tried it but click doesn't seem to fire

Comment: @KDM - well that's how you work with the `this` value in JavaScript.  If it's not working, then you likely have something wrong with one or more of your selectors.

Comment: Im using the sample code that i provided. this is my starting point can you see if you can get it too work

Answer (score 0):

Chaining creates unmaintainable code.  Break it up into separate lines:

```
var $window =  $(window);

$window.resize(function() 
{
    alert('resize')
});

$window.scroll(function() 
{
   alert('scroll')    
});

// etc.
```

Then you can read it, you can step though it with the debugger, you can delete and remove logic with out breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

`window` is an object Window. 
This is window.document which contains HTML objects.

So $(window).find(this) return jquery empty object as $(window).find(document) too.

`$(document).find(this)` works instead which is equivalent of `$(window.document)`.